# How to run check_ncpa.py as a plug-in through NCPA server

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have a pair of servers each running NCPA. One is publicly accessible and the other is hidden behind the other one.

Let's call them `outer.example.com` and `inner.example.com` where `inner.example.com` is `10.0.0.1`.

From the public internet, I'd like to be able to ask `inner.example.com` e.g. how much memory is in use. Doing that on the outer server is easy:

```
$ check_ncpa.py -H outer.example.com -t mytoken -M memory/virtual
OK: Memory usage was 59.40 % (Available: 3.06 GiB, blah blah blah
```

Using the outer server to get to the inner server using `check_ncpa.py` as a plugin *within the NCPA server* should be possible using something like this:

```
$ check_ncpa.py -H outer.example.com -t mytoken -M 'plugins/check_ncpa.py/-H/10.0.0.1/-t/mytoken/-M/memory/virtual'
```

But I get this response instead:

```
UNKNOWN: Unable to run check on node without check method. Requested 'memory' node.
```

Aha! Since `/` is used as a parameter delimiter, that must be the problem. So I url-encode the slash:

```
check_ncpa.py -H 10.0.0.1 -t mytoken -M 'plugins/check_ncpa.py/-H/10.0.0.1/-t/mytoken/-M/memory%2fvirtual'
UNKNOWN: The node (memory%2fvirtual) requested does not exist. You may be trying to access the 'memory' node.
```

☹️

Okay, it looks like we can use the `-a` switch to pass parameters instead of using path segments. This is more actually more readable and, in my opinion, preferable:

```
$ check_ncpa.py -H outer.example.com -t mytoken -M 'plugins/check_ncpa.py' -a '-H 10.0.0.1 -t mytoken -M memory/virtual'
UNKNOWN: Unable to run check on node without check method. Requested 'memory' node.
```

☹️☹️

Do I really have to write my own plug-in (on outer.example.com) to call NCPA-through-NCPA because pretty much every single metric in NCPA requires the use of a slash. Is this a bug in check_ncpa/py, the NCPA server, or am I just *doing it wrong*?

**UPDATE 2023-09-27**

I filed a [bug report with NCPA](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/ncpa/issues/942) about this and it looks like it's something that ought to be supported but isn't quite supported at the moment.